# Tags like 'Windows' should be more general in its filtering

Tags: support, tags, unanswered-questions

There are a few windows tags which includes

- [windows](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows)
- [windows-xp](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-xp)
- [windows-vista](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-vista)
- [windows-7](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-7)

etc

Now, I don't use Linux / Mac / Unix etc, I'm 100% Windows. So when I select the [windows](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows) tag (under unanswered tag on the [unanswered page](https://superuser.com/unanswered)), I would love it to automatically select Windows XP, Windows Vista and Windows 7 (and 8) even if the question was tagged only with Windows-XP. By showing all the various tags also allows me to remove the unwanted too.

This would allow me to see more questions which I may be able to help with and filter out what I don't know.

This could then also be applied to Unix etc.

Maybe I'm being lazy - it's not too hard to select Windows-xp and Windows-vista and Windows-7 and Windows-8 but the fact they change their [position in the list](https://superuser.com/unanswered) (and I understand why) doesn't make this easy.

Or maybe, let me save a group of tags as a bundle which is always selectable at the top of the list of tags?

Any thoughts or comments? Maybe this is impractical.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a trick you may not know: drop in the tilde (`~`) wildcard at the end of the tag name.

Now, when you're looking up `windows~` you'll get all the questions tagged with the text **windows** at the start of the tag name.

https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows~?sort=unanswered

Comment: This is really pretty brilliant - thank you for taking the time to answer.

Comment: another option is to use Favorite tags, which also supports wildcards. Then on [/unanswered](http://superuser.com/unanswered) there's a tab with My tags, which makes use of your favorite tags. Though this will gail if you have multiple tags and you want unanswered of only one tag